# React passing props down through switch element

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I'm having an issue passing props through React elements (like Switch and Route). In the example below, I would like to pass all props of Dashboard component down to the Account component. Is there a way to achieve this?

**App.js**

```
  <Dashboard>
    <Switch>
      // Dashboard props to Account component
      <Route path="/account" render={props => <Account {...props} /> } exact />
      <Route path="/someothercomponent" component={Someothercomponent} />
    </Switch>
  </Dashboard>
```

**Dashboard.js**

```
  render() {
      const children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => {
          var router = React.cloneElement(child, { image: this.state.image });
          return router;
          // Like this the router Element does receive the image prop from
          // the Dashboard component. Now this image prop needs to be
          // passed on to the Account component.

      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like some of the answers already present. To give you a sense of solving this problem differently and also something to learn and add to your toolbox.  I would say use Context.  Context provides a way to pass data through the component tree without having to pass props down manually at every level. https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

So if you get to your Account and have to yet again pass props down this might be a good place to implement this.

When setting up correctly you could do something like this on your page. But again you aren't just passing down one you are passing down all props. And then what if you need to also pass them down on the next component <<< this is the point of Context. I would think using context is better than using a component as your state considering a stateful component is usually limited.  With context, your Account component could have several children and you wouldn't have to pass props all the way down to get done what you wish to achieve.

```
<AppContext.Consumer>
  {({prop1, prop2, prop3}) => {

  }}
 </AppContext.Consumer>
```

That's assuming you name your variable AppContext when you use  React.createContext(); 
The idea is that passing down props at many levels can be annoying for some but using context you can bring a property in at any time without having to worry about if you passed them down correctly. Be sure to read the article in full there are times where you want to use context and times where you do not.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use `render` property instead.

```
<Route path="path" render={() => <MyComponent {...this.props} />} />
```

Comment: I have tried this and unfortunately, it doesn't work. I even tried this with commenting out the <Switch> element and the Account component still doesn't receive the Dashboard component's props

Answer (score 1):

The problem is component is overriding the render props.

Remove `component={Account}`

I've also added brackets  around `(props)` to improve readability

```
<Dashboard> 
  <Switch>
    <Route 
      path="/account"
      render={(props) => <Account {...props} /> } 
      exact 
    /> 
    <Route 
      path="/someothercomponent" 
      component={SomeOtherComponent} 
    />
 </Switch> 
</Dashboard>
```

Alternatively:

```
const renderMergedProps = (component, ...rest) => { 
const finalProps = Object.assign({}, ...rest); 
return( React.createElement(component, finalProps) 
); 
} 

const PropsRoute = ({ component, ...rest }) => { 
  return ( 
    <Route {...rest} render={routeProps => { 
      return renderMergedProps(component, routeProps, rest); 
    }}/> 
  ); 
}

<Router> 
  <Switch> 
    <PropsRoute path='/login' component={Login} auth={auth} authenticatedRedirect="/" />  
    <PropsRoute path='/trades' component={Trades} user={user} />
  </Switch> 
</Router>
```

[source](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4105#issuecomment-289195202)